# Java match regex and extract group oneliner

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple regex like

```
%(\d+)\$@[_a-zA-Z0-9]+@
```

I don't want to write

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(myRegex).matcher(myText);
if (m.matches())
   // do something with m.group(1);
```

What I would really like to do is to have a one liner like

```
// do something with
Pattern.compile(myRegex).matcher(myText).match().group(1);
```

Do you know a good way to do that in Java (I'm using Java 7 but perhaps something changed in 8)?

Comment: And get a nullref exception if the input doesn't match?

Comment: I edited my question not to create a discussion on NumberFormatException or what else can happen if match is not found. I'm perfectly happy if this oneliner will return null or "" if no match

Comment: I think that's a perfectly valid question so please remove the down vote

Comment: I don't understand the close vote neither...

Comment: In Java 9 you'll be to do something like `Pattern.compile(myRegex).matcher(myText).results().map(m -> m.group(1)).findFirst()`.

Comment: Cool, I like that one

Comment: @shmosel could you please add this info about java 9 as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Java 9, you can stream match results and grab the first group of the first result:

```
String result = Pattern.compile(myRegex)
        .matcher(myText)
        .results()
        .map(m -> m.group(1))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Java has gone a long way, and I really like that option

Answer (score -1):

create a static matcher:

```
private static Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(myRegex).matcher("");
```

and use it this way:

```
public String match(String myText, String defaultValue) {
  matcher.reset(myText);
  return matcher.matches() ? matcher.group(1) : defaultValue;
}
```

This is the most efficient way of using regexs (as far as I know).

Comment: `matcher.reset(myText).matches() ? matcher.group(1) : defaultValue` yeah, another good option, thanks

Comment: good point, thanks. I don't really care about thread safety at the moment as I'm writing this in a unit test but overall very important issue

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sure it is not threadsafe. Matcher has an inner state and most class with state aren't threadsafe. But threads weren't mention anywhere.

Comment: @Obenland If you make something static, it is almost guaranteed it will get referenced from multiple threads (even just making it a field would be asking for trouble).